# Datatables warning - ''requested unknown parameter FirstName for row x"

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am having datatables code as follows

````
 <table id="users" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
               <tr>
                     <th>FirstName</th>
                     <th>LastName</th>
                     <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Username</th>
                       <th>Password</th>
                       <th>Email</th>
                      <th>Role</th>
                 </tr>
         <thead>
         <tbody>

         </tbody>
</table>
```
````

And corresponding javascript is as follows

```
 userTable = $("#users").DataTable({
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "scripts/getusers.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json"
    },
    "columns": [
        {data: "FirstName", "orderable": true,"searchable":true,visible:false},
        {data: "LastName", "orderable": true,"searchable":true,visible:false},
        {data : null,
            "render":function(data, type, row, meta ){
            return row['FirstName']+','+row['LastName'];
        }},
        {data: "Username", "orderable": true,"searchable":true},
        {data: "Password", "orderable": true,"searchable":true,
        "render":function(data, type, row, meta ){
            return '********';
        }},
        {data: "Email", "orderable": true,"searchable":true},
        {data: "Role", "orderable": true,"searchable":true,
        "render":function(data, type, row, meta ){
            return data == 1?'Root':(data == 2?'Admin':'User');
        }}
    ],
    "language": {
        "emptyTable": "Seems no users were registered yet"
    },
    dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip'
});
```

When I try to add a row as follows, though the row is added successfully it is showing the warning

> userTable.row.add([data.FirstName,data.LastName,data.Username,data.Password],data.Email,data.Role).draw();
>
> 'requested unknown parameter FirstName for row 10' (my default length is 10)

To update a row I am selecting a row as shown [here](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html) and then calling the following

> userTable.row('.selected').data([data.FirstName,data.LastName,data.Username,data.Password],data.Email,data.Role).draw();

Same error is appearing in the above . It is saying

> 'requested unknown parameter FirstName for row x' (where x is the row number I am updating)
>
> In both the cases row is added and updated successfully. But I am getting the warning.

I guess there is some problem with the render function I wrote for third column.

Also for updating (as shown above) I am calling draw method which is removing the selected class which means I cannot call the above update statement multiple times. Is there any other option. Actually the above update statement is called in a modal dialog. So a same row must be allowed to update multiple times which is not possible if draw() is called which clears the 'selected' class. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. By the time control started rendering the columns it is expecting the object and I am giving an array and also while I am updating the row instead of passing the array I must pass the entire object. During addition due to a bug in my code the 'data' object has not property named FirstName. That is the reason why it is giving the warning. But table is getting updated because I am calling draw() method which reloads the entire table.